# How to change the title size of a plot in pandas (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I read the documentation and even the github link to the source code and I don't see a kwarg to pass in for title size, only for the x and y axis labels. The code below increase size of everything in the figure besides the title. How do people usually increase the title size as well? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as Path

a_path = Path('../'data.csv')
a_dataframe = pd.read_csv(a_path)
a_dataframe.plot(title='Some Title', figsize=(50,25), fontsize=40)
```

Comment: Using [`set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html) perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the axes handle and then call `.title.set_size()`:

```py
ax = a_dataframe.plot(title='Some Title', figsize=(50,25), fontsize=40)
ax.title.set_size(40)
```

Toy example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,0]})
ax = df.plot(title='ax.title.set_size(30)')
ax.title.set_size(30)
```

[image: figure using ax.title.set_size()]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `matplotlib.pyplot`, try below codes.

#### Sample1

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 25, 30]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.plot(x, y, color='lightblue', linewidth=3)
plt.title("Title", fontsize=20)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.plot(x, y, color='lightblue', linewidth=3)
plt.title("Title", fontsize=30)
```

[image]

#### Sample2

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 25, 30]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, color='lightblue', linewidth=3)
ax.set_title('Title', fontdict={'fontsize': 15, 'fontweight': 'bold'})
```

[image]